# detect source download of applications from web like google analytics campaign

Tags: android, google-analytics, referrer, referrals

I'm developing an android app, and publish it to my website. If I publish my app to google play I can use Campaign Measurement to detect source download, and I want to use this feature when I publish my app to my own website to detect my partner IDs when they redirect user who want to download app from their websites to my website.

I have no idea for this problem, have any way to my app knows the query(ex: ?referrer=abc) of url users use to download my apps?

Comment: You can build different .apk on your server for every partner

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it's seem kind of crude, and I try looking for a nice method